# How to combine "IP" and "name" in a list of instances with Terraform local-exec

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to read from Terraform the instance public_IP and the instance_name and then write them into a file in the same line.

Whit the next command, I write the next file:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command =  "echo \"${join("\n", aws_instance.nodeStream.*.public_ip)}\" >> ../ouput_file"
}
```

output_file:

```
34.14.219.13
64.2.201.14
59.12.31.15
```

What I want is to have the next output_file:

```
34.14.219.13 instance_name1
64.2.201.14 instance_name2
59.12.31.15 instance_name3
```

So I have try the next to concat both lists:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
      command =  "echo \"${concat(sort(lookup(aws_instance.node1Stream.*.tags, "Name")), sort(aws_instance.node1Stream.*.public_ip))}\" >> ../../output_file"
    }
```

The previous throws:

```
Error: Invalid function argument: Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument.
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the error and the output of the file?

Comment: @AndyShinn it throws error on deploying: "Error: Invalid function argument: Invalid value for "inputMap" parameter: lookup() requires a map as the first argument."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to produce a string from a data structure, this seems like a good use for [string templates](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates):

```
locals {
  hosts_file_content = <<EOT
    %{ for inst in aws_instance.node1Stream ~}
    ${inst.private_ip} ${inst.tags["Name"]}
    %{ endfor ~}
  EOT
}
```

With that local value defined, you can include it in the `command` argument of the provisioner like this:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "echo '${local.hosts_file_content}' >> ../../output_file"
  }
```

If just getting that data into a file is your end goal, and that wasn't just a contrived example for the sake of this question, I'd recommend using the `local_file` resource instead so that Terraform can manage that file like any other resource, including potentially updating it if the inputs change without the need for any special provisioner triggering:

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_file" {
  filename = "${path.root}/../../output_file"
  content  = <<EOT
    %{ for inst in aws_instance.node1Stream ~}
    ${inst.private_ip} ${inst.tags["Name"]}
    %{ endfor ~}
  EOT
}
```

With that said, the caveat on the `local_file` documentation page applies both to this resource-based approach and the provisioner-based approach: Terraform is designed primarily for managing remote objects that can persist from one Terraform run to the next, not for objects that live only on the system where Terraform is currently running. Although these features do allow creating and modifying local files, it'll be up to you to make sure that the previous file is consistently available at the same location relative to the Terraform configuration next time you apply a change, or else Terraform will see the file gone and be forced to recreate it.